# How to safely convert NVARCHAR to MONEY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, type-conversion

I have an existing table with a 'price_info' column of type `NVARCHAR`. I'd like to add a new column 'price' of type `MONEY` and (where possible) convert/copy the contents of the 'price_info' column into it.

If 'price_info' contains only numeric data, then the value can easily be converted. But of course 'price_info' can also contain data which cannot be converted to type `MONEY` in which case an error occurs.

Is there a way to copy only the values where the conversion to `MONEY` is successful, and silently ignore all other rows (or set the 'price' column to 0 in these cases)?

E.g. what I'd like to have is something like this (pseudo-code):

```
update products set price = some_conversion_function(money, price_info, 0)
```

(where 0 is the default value to be used if the conversion fails).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to do this via script only then you can run 2 updates.

Update 1: Run an update and set the price where ISNUMERIC is true

```
update products 
set price = convert(money, price_info)
where ISNUMERIC(price_info) = 1
```

Update 2: Run an update to set the price to 0 where ISNUMERIC is false.

```
update products 
set price = 0
where ISNUMERIC(price_info) = 0
```

You can get the documentation on ISNUMERIC here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx

Comment: `try_convert` is 2012 only. The question is tagged 2008

Comment: I copied the code from his question directly all I added was the WHERE clause, I actually didn't even know about try_convert, I had assumed that was a custom function they had written. Time to read up on that :)

Comment: Thanks, that works. I didn't know there is a `try_convert` function (as I'm using SQL 2008), but it still works with the normal `convert` function.

Comment: I used `try_convert` just as an example of what I'd like to have (sort of pseudo-code).